# Cannot Bind List<T> to DataGridView in C#!

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

It's 13 December 2013.

I have a List<> that want bind to DataGridView.
It's worked, but today it's not work.

```
public class ExamResult
{
    public string ID;
    public bool Result;
    public bool ReviwerResult;
    public string QuestionFileName;
}
```

then create List :

```
List<ExamResult> result = new List<ExamResult>();
```

Create Instance of ExamResult and Assign value to it's member and then ADD it to  List :

```
//Create a Instance of ExamResult:
ExamResult examResult = new ExamResult();

//Assign Value to members:
examResult.ID="001";
examResult.Result=false;
examResult.ReviewerResult=true;
examResult.QuestionFileName = string.empty;

//Add examResult Instance to List<ExamResult>
result.Add(examResult);
```

then try to bind it to a DataGridView on my WinForm Application.

```
this.DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true; 
this.DataGridView.DataSource = result;
```

But DataGridView Don't Show ANY THING!!!

I swear that this code worked , and now it is not working!!! without changing code.

What is the problem?

Comment: Just take a day off today, make it a long weekend, come back on Monday and it should be fine

Comment: On a serious note, this code should work, Try clean/Rebuild your application. Restart visual studio and make sure you are not clearing your list before binding

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not working'?  Is there an error message?  Are you getting unexpected results?  Nothing at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your class to use properties instead of fields:

```
public class ExamResult
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public bool Result {get; set;}
    public bool ReviwerResult {get; set;}
    public string QuestionFileName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: +1, it appears that code has been changed, and its not Friday the 13th Effect

Comment: why when change 'fields' to 'auto property' it works?

Comment: The bindings are looking for properties, not fields.  See [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)